# Plotting Spherical Coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, spherical-coordinates

I'm trying to plot the Poisson Kernel, where a = 1, so the resulting equation would be
$$P(r,\theta)  = \frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos(\theta)+r^2}$$ 
$0\leq r <a = 1 ,\textrm{ } -\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$

I'm really having trouble visualizing what this function looks like and how to plot it by hand(without using any mathematical software)

Comment: A Google search for “plot Poisson kernel” turns this up: http://wiki.math.toronto.edu/TorontoMathWiki/index.php/Plot_Poisson_Kernel

Answer (score 1):

You may use Maple 18, as I did below, to plot the requried function. Note that I did it where $a=1$:

```
[> restart:
with(plots);
implicitplot3d(z = (-r^2+1)/(1-2*r*cos(t)+r^2), r = 0 .. 1, t = -Pi .. Pi, z = 0 .. 19, numpoints = 110000, axes = boxed, style = surface, color = red);
```

[image]

Apperantly, as I read your comment below, you are not reluctant to do it as we did for you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [SageMath](https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/4fc5f1a4-db16-4459-aa7d-bb2800fd0103/files/Poisson.sagews). You can see the plot there.

[image]

Comment: How would I do this in Sage? You're answer is very vague

Comment: @Doe the link contains the code and the plot. Can you see it?

Comment: @Doe I did a parametric plot in polar coordinates. I used a cutoff at $z=3$ because there is a problematic singularity.

Comment: Ask if there is something that you don't understand

Comment: All the link does is send me to the home page of sage, nothing else

Comment: Sorry. Apparently you need a Sage account to see the code. I can upload the image, if you want to.

Comment: yes please that would be very helpful, thank you

Comment: @Doe if you enter Sage you can rotate the graph in 3D and change the range, but this might be enough to get an idea.